# Case Label Does Not reduce to integer constant

Tags: c++, char, integer, switch-statement, constants

I'm not understanding why my switch statement is not working.
I've chopped it up since it was rather long, but the user is supposed to input a character to "selection1' & "selection2" and then I pass those as a parameter to my validSelection() function. The validSelection function is supposed to test the characters for the valid entries and deny all others by returning a boolean.

```
bool validSelection(char selection)
{
switch (selection)
{
case "R":
case "r":
case "P":
case "p":
case "S":
case "s":
    return true;
default:
    return false;
}
}

cin >> selection1;
cin >> selection2;
if (validSelection(selection1) && validSelection(selection2))
```

selection1 and selection2 both are char data types.

Comment: `"R"` is a string literal. `'R'` is a character literal. Guess which one is an integer constant.

Comment: lol your username is coincidental, I was completely oblivious to what I did. I've been through this exact same situation before too! Deja vu :(

Comment: One of many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12874960/62576 In the future, please do a search here first for the error message you're receiving; chances are quite high that a question has been asked (and answered) about the problem before here, particularly with code written by new programmers in C/C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @CaptainObvlious has already pointed out, anything between double-quotes `""` is considered as string. However, you ant to pass the integer value to the switch. For the same, you have to put the characters inside single-quotes `''`.

You may need to change our code as below.

```
bool validSelection(char selection)
{
    switch (selection)
    {
        case 'R':
        case 'r':
        case 'P':
        case 'p':
        case 'S':
        case 's':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```